# Hook_form_FORM_ID_alter problems with custom validating

Tags: forms

I have created a custom module for altering the user_register_form and with custom validating I have an error:
Notice: Undefined index: values in custom_register_validate_password() (line 17

This is the 17 line:

```
if (in_array($form['values']['pass'], $badpasswords)) {
```

I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong. Here's the full code:

```
<?php

    /*
     * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
     */
    function custom_register_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

        $form['#validate'][] = 'custom_register_validate_password';
        //krumo($form);
     }

     /*
      * Custom password validation
      */
    function custom_register_validate_password($form, &$form_state) {
        $badpasswords = array('pass','password');
        if (in_array($form['values']['pass'], $badpasswords)) {
            form_set_error('pass', t('Please use a more secure password!'));
        }
        krumo($form_state);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to write

```
    if (in_array($form_state['values']['pass'], $badpasswords)) {
        form_set_error('pass', t('Please use a more secure password!'));
    }
```

`$form_state['values']['pass']` instead `of $form['values']['pass']`

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. The strange thing is that I've followed the right example from the video tutorials "Module development for Drupal 7" made by Lulabot/Drupalize.me and I don't know how come when they're using     if (in_array($form['values']['pass'], $badpasswords)) { and it's working, but not in mine case.  Thank you.